# Using UUIDField as User primary key

Tags: python, django, django-models

Django 1.8 offers a [UUIDField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield). Is there a way to use this field as the primary key for User without creating a custom User model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Django's built in user will use an [`AutoField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#autofield) as the primary key. If you want to change it, you need a custom user model.